# Get node value in linkedlist from end in c

Tags: c, function, return, return-value, return-type

I am doing this hackerrank question (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/get-the-value-of-the-node-at-a-specific-position-from-the-tail)
My code is as follows -

```
int GetNode(Node *head,int positionFromTail)
{
  Node *prev = NULL;
  Node *current = head;
  Node *next;
  while(current!=NULL){
     next = current->next;
     current->next = prev;
     prev = current;
     current = next;
  }
  head = prev;
  int p=0;
  while(head->next!=NULL){
    if(p== positionFromTail){
        return head->data;
    }
    else {
        p++;
        head= head->next;
    }
  } 
}
```

So what i have done is, I have first reversed the linkedlist and then looped for the specific position and then printed its value. Is it correct method to do it?
It gives me this error.

```
  solution.cc: In function ‘int GetNode(Node*, int)’:
  solution.cc:42:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [Werror=return-type]
   }
   ^
   cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: you need to return an integer because the prototype of your function says so. I thought the message was clear.

Comment: yes , but (return head->data) is an integer.

Comment: Where do you ***`return`*** anything? You *do* know about the `return` statement? Perhaps you should [read a couple of good books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: Your function needs to return an integer in every case of your if conditions, or simply you can return an integer at the end of the function.
Problem here is the compiler thinks that nothing is being returned when the condition if(p== positionFromTail) never becomes true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each possible branch which might leave the function needs to return a value.

If the initial `head->next` would be `NULL` the `return` statement you coded would not be reached.

Design your code to have a function have only one *possible* exit-point.

This might look like the following:

```
/* returns pay-load or INT_MIN if list is empty or searched pos is negativ*/

int GetNode(Node *head, int positionFromTail)
{
  int result = INT_MIN;

  ...

  while (head->next != NULL) {
    if(p == positionFromTail) {
      result = head->data;
      break;
    }
    else {
      p++;
      head = head->next;
    }
  } 

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement makes it impossible for the code to reach the end of your function without returning a value, because of this constraint:

> **Constraints**
>
> Position will be a valid element in linked list.

However, C compiler has no idea that your `while` loop would never exit upon reaching `NULL`, guaranteeing that `return head->data` is eventually executed, so it issues an error.

You can fix this by providing an unused `return` at the end, or by making your loop infinite.

**Note:** Your solution reverses the list, which may be non-optimal. You can avoid reversal by storing `positionFromTail + 1` trailing items in an array as you traverse the list once:

```
int GetNode(Node *head,int positionFromTail) {
    int data[++positionFromTail], p = 0;
    while (head) {
        data[p] = head->data;
        head = head->next;
        p = (p+1) % positionFromTail;
    }
    return data[p];
}
```